# Docker for Windows: No permissions over folders inside `C:\ProgramData\Docker`

Tags: windows, docker, docker-desktop

I'm not sure since which version, but the permissions for the files and subfolders inside the `C:\ProgramData\Docker` folder have changed. I'm not able to display the current owner and I'm not able to delete the contents of the volumes anymore.

Below image shows the permissions over the `plugins` folder, but every file and folder inside `C:\ProgramData\Docker` is showing the same thing.

[image]

The current user is a member of the groups `Administrators` and `docker-users`.
Is this a known issue for anyone and is there a nice way to fix this?

Comment: Do you find the solution for this?

Comment: I don't have access to that laptop anymore but I believe I tried a different (newer) version and it solved itself that way.